# AMPscript lookup not returning value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

fairly easy question here I guess but I'm having problems with it.

So I was trying an AMPscript exercise in trailhead:
[image: Trailhead example script]

Also, can be found here as exercise 3: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/ampscript-for-nondevelopers/practice-using-ampscript

Now in my own environment, I tried this with different variables:

```
%%[
    Var @Subscriber_Key
    Set @Subscriber_Key = Subscriber_Key
    Var @CardNumber
    Set @CardNumber = Lookup("CARDS_DE","Card_Number","Subscriber_Key",@Subscriber_Key) 
]%%
    %%=v(CardNumber)=%%
```

I didn't get an error but it didn't return any values. I used the same structure to make this script as in example. Is there something I'm missing here? The attributes should be right.

Attributes in CARDS_DE: Card_Number, Subscriber_Key, Date_Created

Subscriber_Key is also in the "Master DE".

Comment: How did you test this - in an email? Did you preview against a subscriber?

Comment: Yes, I tested this in an email and used the preview functionality.

Comment: OK, but did you preview against a subscriber? Do you have a `Subscriber_Key` column in your sendable Data Extension?

Comment: Yes, written exactly the same way.

Comment: And do you have a `Subscriber_Key` column in `CARDS_DE`? Can you update your original question with the structure of your sendable DE and the `CARDS_DE`?

Comment: Yes, I modified the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. The problem is in your code, you've forgetten the `@` character before `CardNumber` variable in the last line..

Try this:

```
%%[
    Var @Subscriber_Key
    Set @Subscriber_Key = Subscriber_Key
    Var @CardNumber
    Set @CardNumber = Lookup("CARDS_DE","Card_Number","Subscriber_Key",@Subscriber_Key) 
]%%
    %%=v(@CardNumber)=%%
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Comment: nice, didn't notice that :-)

Comment: Thanks! You've cleared out almost all other possibilities :)